# Set a variable equal to itself unless it doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I'm parsing the Linkedin API right now and you can request various fields and their values. Sometimes a user has a value for a field, other times they don't.

For example, if the user didn't put in a phone number, Linkedin won't return a phone number field.

**Example Request to Linkedin**

`email, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber`

**Example Response from Linkedin:**

```
{"email"=>"test@example.com", "firstName"=>"Brian", "lastName"=>"Weinreich"}
```

So, I request 4 things: `email, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber` and it only returns 3 things. I was wondering if there is a quicker / more efficient way of setting a variable equal to these values, depending on whether or not they exist.

This is how I'm doing it... but it seems redundant.

```
@user.email = profile['emailAddress'] ? profile['emailAddress'] : ""
@user.phone_number = profile['phoneNumber'] ? profile['phoneNumber'] : ""
@user.first_name = profile['firstName'] ? profile['firstName'] : ""
@user.last_name = profile['lastName'] ? profile['lastName'] : ""
```

Comment: 2 clarifying questions: 1) Why not just leave the attribute `nil`? 2) Where are you setting these attributes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@user.email = profile['emailAddress'] || ""
@user.phone_number = profile['phoneNumber'] || ""
@user.first_name = profile['firstName'] || ""
@user.last_name = profile['lastName'] || ""
```

Comment: Okay, that was easy hah. Thanks. What is that called for future reference?

Comment: I know it's an "OR" statement, but why does it default to the empty string? Is it because the profile['emailAddress'] is false?

Comment: The more correct way to say this is because profile['emailAddress'] is _falsy_. The two falsy things in ruby are `nil` and `false`.

Comment: Also: you can avoid the `|| ""` part by doing this `profile['emailAddress'].to_s` (since `nil.to_s` returns `""`)

Answer (score 3):

That's fairly simple - set the default value for a Hash:

```
> profile={"email"=>"test@example.com", "firstName"=>"Brian", "lastName"=>"Weinreich"}
=> {"email"=>"test@example.com", "firstName"=>"Brian", "lastName"=>"Weinreich"}
> profile.default = ""
=> ""
```

then just simple assignment would do what you've required:

```
@user.email = profile['emailAddress']
@user.phone_number = profile['phoneNumber']
@user.first_name = profile['firstName']
@user.last_name = profile['lastName']
```

You may also set instead of one default value `Proc` block for more complex cases:

```
profile.default_proc= proc {|hash, key| hash[key] = (key =~ /email/i) ? "default@example.com" : ""}

> profile['email']
=> "test@example.com"
> profile['hiddenEmail1234']
=> "default@example.com"
> profile['some-other-key']
=> ""
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. Thanks!